# Convert UTC time to provided Timezone, must not depend on browser timezone

Tags: jquery, datetime, timezone, momentjs

This kind of question is asked before but I have little tricky situation. 
I have a datetime that's in UTC. I want to convert it specific timezone whatever we pass. 
Currently i am using moment-timezone library.
What happens with it is, it considers the provided time in browser's timezone and then try to convert it in provided timezone.
I want to make provided time to be considered in UTC.

js code :

```
var datetime = '2015/04/10 15:35:00';
datetime = moment(datetime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
datetime = moment.utc(datetime);
return moment(datetime).tz(siteTimeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

i have also tried by directly applying utc like:

```
var datetime = '2015/04/10 15:35:00';
datetime = moment.utc(datetime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
return moment(datetime).tz(siteTimeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

but none of them work as expected. May i am not clear about how moment-timezone is working.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parse as utc before converting to the time zone.

```
var datetime = '2015/04/10 15:35:00';

return moment.utc(datetime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')
             .tz(siteTimeZone)
             .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Note also that I provided a format string while parsing, which matched the format of the value being passed in.  This is a good practice, and will prevent moment from generating a warning on the console.

Comment: If it was already in utc, then why are you converting it to utc again using moment.utc?

Comment: @ParkashKumar -  There are two forms of the function.  `moment.utc(s)` doesn't convert.  It parses the input value, creating a `moment` object, *interpreting* it as UTC in the process.  The other form is `moment(s).utc()`, which converts from local time to utc.

Answer (score 0):

Take your string in Date object, then get UTC string from it using `datetime.toUTCString()` and finally set timeZone & format, as following:

Following is the tested code:

```
var datetime = new Date('2015/04/10 15:35:00');
datetime = datetime.toUTCString();
datetime = moment(new Date(datetime)).tz(siteTimeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nz0w4mo5/)

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't address the problem.  The OP stated that the value was *originally* in UTC.  All this really does is the same thing as the OP's first example.  The two `Date` objects are extraneous.